# Extract a section from the filename of a Batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, parameter-passing

File: `Test 123 - Test 456 - Test 789.txt`

I need to extract the first section from a passed parameter inside a Batch file. In this case it would be "Test 123" but the files always have different names. " -" needs to be the delimiter (space + hyphen).

`%~n1` expands `%1` to file name only but how to specify only one section of the filename?

**Edit**: Thanks for all the help but only the PowerShell solution from LotPings works as expected! The others echoed an empty filename. I don't know why but I'm sure it has something to do with my setup.

Comment: Set it to a variable and expand it with substitution, or run it through a loop delimited as required. If you want more specific help, provide a [mcve] code snippet, so that we can put responses into the context of your actual issue.

Comment: Had you followed the advice in my last comment, and provided the code you needed help with, the answers could have been provided in a format which suited you environment. The fault is entirely yours and it's unfair of you to those discount those correct answers for that reason. Please make sure you take the [tour] and understand [ask] before posting any further questions; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another solution using PowerShell**

```
@Echo off
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('
Powershell -NoP -C "('%~1' -Split ' - ')[0]"
') Do Set "NewName=%%A%~x1"
Set NewNAme
```

---

```
>  SO_50887843_2.cmd " -;Test 123 - Test 456 =! Test 789.txt"
NewName= -;Test 123.txt
```

With string substitution you can do a bit shuffling (with unquoted arguments)

```
:: SO_50887843.cmd
@Echo off
Set "_Args=%*"
:: remove content up to first delimiter " - "
Set "_Rest=%_Args:* - =%"
:: remove " - " and Rest from Args
Call Set "_First=%%_Args: - %_Rest%=%%"
Set _
```

---

```
> SO_50887843.cmd Test 123 - Test 456 - Test 789.txt
_Args=Test 123 - Test 456 - Test 789.txt
_First=Test 123
_Rest=Test 456 - Test 789.txt
```

With quoted args change 2nd line to:

```
Set "_Args=%~1"
```

Comment: Thanks, the PowerShell solution works! Just needed to replace `%~1` with `%~n1` and `%%A%~x1` with `%%A`.

Comment: Well I think all the approaches do work - thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 2):

…And another:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "filename=%~n1"
Set "newname=%filename: -="&:"%"
Echo "%newname%%~x1"
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

This commented code can be used for this task:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Get file name without extension and path assigned to an environment variable.
set "FileName=%~n1"

rem For file names starting with a dot and not having one more dot like .htaccess.
if not defined FileName set "FileName=%~x1"

rem Exit the batch file if passed argument is a folder path ending with a backslash.
if not defined FileName goto EndBatch

rem Replace each occurrence of space+hyphen+space and next also of just
rem space+hyphen by a vertical bar in file name. A vertical bar is used
rem because a file name cannot contain this character.
set "FileName=%FileName: - =|%"
set "FileName=%FileName: -=|%"

rem Get first vertical bar delimited string assigned to the environment variable.
for /F "eol=< delims=|" %%I in ("%FileName%") do set "FileName=%%I"

echo First part of "%~nx1" is "%FileName%".

rem Add here more commands using the environment variable FileName.

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

This batch file must be called with the file name enclosed in double quotes because of file name contains paces, for example:

```
GetFirstFileNamePart.bat "Test 123 - Test 456 - Test 789.txt"
```

This batch file works even on calling it with following very strange file name:

```
GetFirstFileNamePart.bat " - Test 123 -Test 456 != Test 789 & More.txt"
```

The output is in this case:

```
First part of " - Test 123 -Test 456 != Test 789 & More.txt" is "Test 123".
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`